# Create multiple C++ files in the same project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++ and wanted to know how can we create individual runnable C++ files in the same project in Visual Studio? My goal is to be able to run each file individually and not create a different project for each file. 
Kindly help me...

Thank you..

Regards,
Karan Manghi

Comment: That's not the way Visual Studio works.  For every executable output you need a project.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Ransom states, you need a project per executable/library in Visual Studio. However, you could create a Visual Studio Solution with multiple executable projects, with one file each.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks Alan and Mark!

Comment: @Estrella, Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers.